# self-invoking function issue javascript

Tags: javascript

I am suppose to use a function expression to display the date when the page loads then use a self invoking function to change the date font color.

I thought I was on the right path but I have two issues. The first one is, my code doesnt change the color of text. the second one, is i get a console error from the first function saying the dateDisplay(); is not defined. but if I try to remove the function name from the call and just use (); to run the function. I get the error

```
document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d; is null
```

I had tried to change several things and I just wind up with console errors. generally i either get function not defined, or an error like the one above.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2><p id="dateDisplay"></p></h2>
    <p>does this work</p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var d = new Date();
 window.onload = function dateDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d;
}
();

(function (){
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").style.color="red";
})();
```

Im quite lost and dont understand whats going on.

Comment: I pasted you code like it is into codepen and it worked :)

Comment: You shouldn't have the `();` on the 5th line of your JavaScript. Also, if your script block is above the div where the `dateDisplay` element is defined, then the element will not exist at the time that the self-invoking function expression is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d;
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").style.color = "red";
};
```

or even better:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").innerHTML = d;
    document.getElementById("dateDisplay").style.color = "red";
});
```

or you can also do:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var d = new Date(),
        display = document.getElementById("dateDisplay");
    display.innerHTML = d;
    display.style.color = "red";
});
```

Comment: Where is the self-invoking function?

Comment: There is no self invoking functions. You don't need them anyway since it's the browser's responsibility to execute your code at the right time.

Comment: But the homework assignment (I assume that's what this is) says to use a self-invoking function. You can't change the assignment just because it's not the way you would code it.

Comment: I don't actually see any places you would want to use a self invoking function...

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing homework that requires you to do it a certain way?

Anyway I thought I'd give a couple pointers to help out. First off, if something doesn't work and I don't understand it much (still learning it) I like to break it down to smaller parts and test until I get a better understanding.

For instance try just one of your functions with `console.log` until you get it working:

```
var d = new Date();

window.onload = function() {
    console.log('window loaded!');
}
```

This function should work just fine when you load, if it does not then something else is wrong.  Once you get this working then add in the `document.getElem...` and work on the next function etc.

edit, showing my quick test:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var d = new Date();

window.onload = function() {
    console.log('window loaded');
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = d;
}

(function() {
    console.log('invoked');
    document.getElementById('header').style.color = 'red';
}());
```

worked just fine.

Comment: yes this is a homework assignment, so I assume I have to do it a certain way, but the instructions are very confusing and vague

Comment: Your code up top, though not ideal, does work. Depending on your instructor, he/she might like if you found another route. I was always years ahead of my class so when he asked for a text game, I made a 2d game. However, since you're just learning you might want to at least figure out hwy your code didn't work for you first.

Comment: well could you help me out a bit, cause i dont understand why it doesnt work. i get console errors I stated in my question. I dont really like the way the instructions state, seems very sloppy

Comment: i get an error thrown saying dateDisplay element value is null, when Im trying to set the value

Comment: It's hard for me to say, is that 100% of your code?

Comment: yes, the wierd thing is it works on jsfiddle and codpen, but when i use komodo ide to view via firefox, it does not work and i get console error

Comment: the only other code involved is html, link my js file and giving my page a title etc etc. very basic

Comment: this is what chrome says.....program04script.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null from searching that phrase its basically saying that my javascript is being called before the element was in the DOM